# Does clang think I need to point to a "const function"?

Tags: c++, function-pointers, clang++, reinterpret-cast, const-correctness

[<kbd>GodBolt</kbd>](https://godbolt.org/z/qEn3q7)

Consider the following code snippet:

```
using A = void(*)(int);

A foo(const void* ptr) 
{
    return reinterpret_cast<A>(ptr);
}
```

GCC 10 likes this just fine. clang++-10, however, says this is an error!

```
<source>:5:12: error: reinterpret_cast from 'const void *' to 'A' (aka 'void
 (*)(int)') casts away qualifiers

    return reinterpret_cast<A>(ptr);

           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Functions aren't mutable in C++ (and C), and there are no "const functions". So why is clang++ complaining here?

Comment: Try ````reinterpret_cast<const A*>(ptr)```

Comment: @OutOfBound: Sneaky! ... but - it doesn't work. Do it at the GodBolt link and you'll see the function return type has to change.

Comment: Because you can not cast away the const qualifier with reinterpret_cast. It doesn't matter, that funcion pointers are immutable.

Comment: @OutOfBound: But I'm not casting away a const qualifier - because function pointers are immutable, i.e. inherently const, i.e. you don't change anything by writing through them.

Comment: Aren't there some big caveats about casting function pointers to data pointers, and vice versa?  (Regular function pointers, not member function pointers which are an entirely different beast.)

Comment: `std::is_const` returns false for function types, so a function pointer is technically not a pointer to `const`. You can't write through them because function types are incomplete (I think), not because they're `const`.

Comment: @Eljay: Well, not big enough to be caught by `-Wall -Wextra` apparently.

Comment: AFAIK it's illegal to cast a function pointer to a `void*` so that would make clang correct.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: Touche.

Comment: @NathanOliver: clang doesn't complain if it's a `void*`.

Comment: Then it's wrong for that case.  Really though when you use `reinterpret_cast` you are basically telling the compiler ignore what I'm doing because I know what I'm doing.  That's why for the most part you don't get any warnings or errors.  It is nice to see that at least clang is looking for the removal of `const`.

Comment: @NathanOliver I don't remember the exact status of `void *` <-> "function pointer" conversions, but I don't think it's "ill-formed". Probably "implementation-defined if supported or not", or something along those lines.

Comment: @NathanOliver: I'd say it's a bit silly to ignore the reinterpretation to a different pointer type, but fail me on a pure formality (seeing how I'm not effectively discarding constness and "threatening" to write through the pointer).

Comment: `return (A)ptr;` I mean, it's a valid workaround :)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat `reinterpret_cast` only allows function pointer to function pointer casts: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.reinterpret.cast#6.  `static_cast` only talks about  casting object pointers to `void*` and a function pointer is not an object pointer.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Ah oops, missed a pragraph.  It is conditionally supported: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.reinterpret.cast#8

Comment: @Ayxan: I like the way you think >:-) ...

Comment: Even if the compiler if free to conditionally support this conversion according to the standard, Clang behavior looks idiotic, so this is certainly a bug.

Answer (score 2):

Because the standard says so.

[expr.reinterpret.cast]/2:

> The `reinterpret_­cast` operator shall not cast away constness.

[expr.const.cast]/7:

> A conversion from a type `T1` to a type `T2` *casts away constness* if `T1` and `T2` are different, there is a cv-decomposition of `T1` yielding n such that `T2` has a cv-decomposition of the form
> [image: CV-decomposition of T2]
>
> and there is no qualification conversion that converts `T1` to
> [image: CV-decomposition of T1]

Here T1 is `const void*`, T2 is `void (*)(int)`, n = 1, the cv-decomposition of `T2` has cv0 = "", P0 = "pointer to", cv1 = "", U2 = `void(int)`, so the corresponding version of `T1` is `void*`. There is no qualification conversion from `const void*` to `void*`. It follows that the conversion casts away constness and cannot be performed by `reinterpret_cast`.

Comment: You're assuming that T2 can be a function type and the definition can still hold. But that doesn't make sense, because the whole point of being const is the guarantee of no writes through the pointer, and "casting away constness" is casting away this guarantee.  anti-common-sense interpretations of the standard - well, they don't make sense. But +1 for explaining what clang seems to be doing.

Answer (score 0):

Alert this is not producion friendly code !

```
using A = void(*)(int);

A foo(const void* ptr)
{
    union McGayver {
         const void* ptr;
         A a;
    } u;
    u.ptr = ptr;
    return u.a;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/1e1oE6

Comment: Agreed, undefined behavior and non-optimizable code is never production friendly.